# Cocoa Core Data and plain text file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm wrinting a very simple application which can read data from a specified file and populate the fetched data to a `NSTableView`. The file is a plain text file where each line represents an object (I need to parse the file). I want to use Core Data and my question is what is the Cocoa way to do that?

My first idea is to parse the file and create instances for the Entity which represents one line. I'm not sure that is it the best solution. And later I'll write out the changes to the file (after save? or automatically after a given amount of time?)

My configuration is Mountain Lion and the latest XCode.

Comment: How many attributes do the object have? Why write back out to a file (you want to use Core Data just for in-memory caching?)?

Comment: The Entity is really simple: it has 6 attributes. I planned to store the parsed entities in memory. The application will be a basic _CRUD_ app, users can add and delete entries, that's why I want to write back to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single entity with a number of attributes sounds good. If you had an attribute which holds a reasonable amount of data and was repeated on a number of 'rows' then it would be a candidate for another entity.

Yes, each instance of your entity would represent one row in your table.

Personally, I would either save on request by the user, or not have a save button and save each change. Your issue is the conversion between your in-memory store and on-disk store. Using a plain text file doesn't help (though, depending on the file format, it could be possible to edit individual lines in the file using `NSFileHandle`).

Generally it would still make more sense to use a better format like XML or JSON and then make use of a framework like RestKit which will do all of the parsing and mapping for you (after you specify the mapping configuration).

You can also use [bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW59) to connect your data to your `NSTableView`. [Another ref](http://pinkstone.co.uk/binding-an-nstableview-to-core-data-without-code/).

Comment: I have to use the plain text file because other applications are still use it. You're right, the application should save the data in memory when an user made any changes, and later will write out to disk. One thing I don't fully understand: I bind the in memory data to various GUI elements via cocoa binding, but how can I make for the lines and how can I feed them to Core Data?

Comment: Presumably each line in your source file represents a row and has a set format, so you need to parse through it (`NSScanner`) and create and update instances of your entity.

Comment: Now I'm struggling for the file writing. When the program starts I read the whole file and parse each lines, but before save it I have to check whether the file changed or not. (Because it's possible to an another client changes the file). I don't know how should I do that in Cocoa, read the file again before I write out?

Comment: Use `NSFileManager` to get the file attributes and check the last modified date. P.s. Please accept answers that are correct / up vote answers that helped. Thanks.